# AngularJS - Deep watch in a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the following directive:

```
{
  scope: { 'id' : '=id' }
  link: function ($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('id', function(x) { console.debug(x); });
  }
}
```

Which I invoke like this:

```
<my-directive id="Item.ToWatch" />
```

Now what I want is to update `Item` on my `Scope`, and for the watch function setup in the directive to be invoked.

Currently it does not do so, how can I get this to work? Is it not supposed to work this way, can it not see if any part of the binding path references change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my own fault. I had my directive binding correct. This kind of deep watching does infact work :)